# New Relic javascript cdn link?

Tags: newrelic

Is there a CDN link for the new relic agent script that I can use to embed in the index.html of my client side react app?
Or, should I get the javascript content and save in a file and then reference that file in index.html?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think New Relic has a CDN link to embed in the index.html. As you said, you will have to get the javascript content, save it in a file and then reference that file in index.html.

My team came across the same problem recently but eventually, we moved to another observability platform (Datadog).